# Silverlight and MySQL Problem

Tags: c#, php, mysql, silverlight

I am currently looking into developing a silverlight app with a MySQL Backend however I am having big problems with it.

Below is my PHP Code:

```
<?php
    include("config.php");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM test_table";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    $array=array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $array[] = array("FirstName"=>$row['firstName'], 
            "LastName"=>$row['lastName'],
            "Age"=>$row['age']);

    }
    mysql_close();

    $returnItems = array("returnType"=>"Names",
        "results"=>$returnItems);

    $JSONResult = json_encode($array);

    echo $JSONResult;
?>
```

Below is my C# Silverlight Code

```
WebClient wc;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            wc = new WebClient();
            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
        }

        private void btnGetData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("/getData.php"));

        }

        void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Downloading Data 2");
            try
            {
                JsonValue completeResult = JsonPrimitive.Parse(e.Result);
                string resultType = completeResult["returnType"].ToString().Replace('"', ' ').Trim();

                JsonArray arrayJson = (JsonArray)completeResult["results"];
                foreach (JsonValue item in arrayJson)
                {
                    string firstName = arrayJson["FirstName"].ToString().Replace('"', ' ').Trim();

                    MessageBox.Show("First Name: " + firstName);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
```

When I click on the button which should retrieve data on the line

```
string resultType = completeResult["returnType"].ToString().Replace('"', ' ').Trim();
```

it goes into the catch which says
'This method or property is not supported on a JSON value of type System.Json.JsonArray. Some operations may only be performed on JSON arrays and some may only be performed on JSON objects.

I'm not sure what I can try to resolve this problem.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Is it me, or should that be `json_encode($returnItems);`?

Comment: I tried what you suggested but then when I manually run the PHP Script in the browser it doesn't come up with any data from MySQL it just says {"returnType":"Names","results":null}

Comment: Boardy, if you would develop with error_reporting to `E_ALL` & display_errors on, you'd see a mention of `$returnItems` not being defined. Solution would be: `$returnItems = array("returnType"=>"Names","results"=>$array)`;

Comment: @Wrikken I tried the line you suggested but it is still displaying the same error message within Silverlight

Comment: OK, but you now actually have a "returnType" entry in your json, with a filled 'results' array? That's about it what I can do for you, don't know diddly-squat about Silverlight, so that's for others to determine :)

Comment: @Wrikken Thanks for your help. I've managed to sort it out now I was calling the wrong name in silverlight for PHP from when I was trying to get it to work. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you execute query in xml mode?

In MSSQL after the select command add FOR XML PATH('Node')

then
xml.linq.xelement test = Xml.Linq.Xelement.Parse(e.result)

Tiz